# How to click revealed views while swiping RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I use this [RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator](https://github.com/xabaras/RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator) to implement revealing views while swiping on RecyclerView like this:
[image]

[image]

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                try {
                    final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                    if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT){
                       // prepare to delete
                    }
                    else {
                      // prepare to edit
                    }

                 
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            // You must use @RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator inside the onChildDraw method
            @Override
            public void onChildDraw (Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive){
                new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                        .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.recycler_view_item_swipe_left_background))
                        .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_archive_white_24dp)
                        .addSwipeRightBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.recycler_view_item_swipe_right_background))
                        .addSwipeRightActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit_white_24dp)
                        .addSwipeRightLabel(getString(R.string.action_delete))
                        .setSwipeRightLabelColor(Color.WHITE)
                        .addSwipeLeftLabel(getString(R.string.action_edit))
                        .setSwipeLeftLabelColor(Color.WHITE)
                        .create()
                        .decorate();
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvProducts);
```

So far it's good. I can easily determine wether user is swiping left or right. Now the question is, how to make the "Edit" and "Delete" views clickable?